# Xamarin iOS framework binding fail to find attributes in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

In the solution all attributes are not recognized, any idea how to resolve this?

I used Sharpie to generate the ApiDefinitions and Structs cs files using `sharpie init ios Stripe` and `sharpie ios bind`.

Second issue is that one type is not created but I could manually add it if I can pass the first problem. Any comment on this one would be great help.

Find the Github repository code here,
https://github.com/xplatsolutions/Stripe-Xamarin-iOS-Bindings.

Comment: Any specific reason for this binding project? Because stripe component is already on Xamarin store.

Comment: If you noticed, Xamarin store Stripe component is updated 3 years ago, it is a dead project. If you visit the Github code of this component you will see related issues asking about the status of the project with no replies. Another reason is that it is managed C# classes not the actual bindings the controllers 'out of the box' views are not included to use in your application. I will add one more, latest version of Stripe iOS is 10.1.0, 3 years ago it was most probably 2.0. https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases. In a new project wouldn't you want to align with the actual documentation?

Comment: Agree! We can work together to make it live. I worked on some binding project before.

Comment: @RIYAZ I just updated the repo with a working build code but needs testing, I will have time to test tomorrow, if you do earlier let me know the results. Couple of weird generated bindings that I didn't get, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually transferred the types generated one by one and modified accordingly to make the project build. Feel free to check out the repository in Github.

Still some answers needed, like why the [VerifyAttribute] is not recognized and why two types marked as [Category] and have instance members.